# How to handle (constant) string set in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, string, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms project.
I would like to organize different strings placed in many classes: how is best pattern to handle constant string? (maybe the question, if Xamarin doesn't support it, is related to generic .net application).

Static class with get/set string properties?
Enum of strings? (i haven't tried yet)

Thank you for any suggestion!

Lewix

Answer (score 2):

I prefer using .Net resources files (resx) for strings. This makes it easier to locate application strings in the project and internationalization is natively supported for all platforms without platform-specific code or resources, so no `Localizable.plist` on iOS or `strings` file on Android. This also helps to non-technical team members to modify these files with one of the [many](https://sourceforge.net/projects/resx/) [existing](http://resex.codeplex.com) [resx](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3b64e04c-e8de-4b97-8358-06c73a97cc68) [editors](https://zetaresourceeditor.codeplex.com).

In addition, you get **static class** with **constants** for all defined strings.

Example extracted from the [xamarin docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/advanced/localization/):

`AppResources.resx`:

```
<data name="NotesLabel" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Notes:</value>
    <comment>label for input field</comment>
</data>
<data name="NotesPlaceholder" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>eg. buy milk</value>
    <comment>example input for notes field</comment>
</data>
<data name="AddButton" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Add new item</value>
</data>
```

Usage in code:

```
myLabel.Text = AppResources.NotesLabel;
myEntry.Placeholder = AppResources.NotesPlaceholder;
myButton.Text = AppResources.AddButton;
```

Obtaining a consistent behavior on all platforms:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about application wide constant strings that represent information that configure the context that they are in (i.e. connectionstrings, URL's, etc) then you can put store those in the properties of your application. This way you can change the configuration outside of your solution as well, by changing the config file.

If you do not want to store the data in a configuration file, then storing them in a static class is not a terrible option, I know of people that like to define such constants in their `Program`class (e.g. `Program.Constants.<constant>`. I myself choose to only define constants where I need them, rather than exposing them to the entire application, unless they are configuration variables. In that case I use the properties of the application.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx